# Java + ResultSet.getObject()

Tags: java, xml, jdbc

We have two identical setups of our product at our end. One setup is working properly but the other setup has encountered the below problem.

We are firing a query on the database and the query is like :

```
String query = select col1_name, col2_name, col3_name from table_1;
PreparedStatement l_statement = null;
Connection con = "<connection-string>";
l_statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
Resultset l_rs = l_statement.executeQuery();
```

Now the col1("column1") datatype is "SYS.XMLTYPE" the code to fetch the column-data is :

```
Object obj = null;
obj = l_rs.getObject(1);
String xmlStr = null;
if(obj instanceof XMLTYPE){
  ...
} lse if (obj instanceof XMLTYPE){
  ...
} else if (obj instanceof java.sql.SQLXML){
   xmlStr = ((SQLXML)obj).getString ();
}
```

The control of the program goes in the last else if, i.e.

```
xmlStr = ((SQLXML)obj).getString ();
```

Now when we inspect the value of xmlStr, it contains junk characters as:

```
Ÿcž(too many junk characters.)
```

On one setup this piece of code works correctly and on other, the xml String gives junk characters, what could be the reason?

Comment: Obviously something is different :-) Have you verified DB encodings, server encodings etc?

Comment: Could you show us what are the differences of your setups?

Comment: if **two identical setups** , try to swap the machines (bugged setup on the working machine and vice versa) . _reason for such a suggestion : check if database is corrupted_

Comment: Both setups point to same database. What is the role of server encoding in this? It is not present on both servers. The only difference between two setups is that, one setup is on linux and other on windows.

Comment: What are the default encodings on the separate servers? Did you try explicitly setting the encoding on the servers to that of the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to specify what String encoding you're expecting. By default Windows and Linux have different default encodings so they may be incompatible when you marshall on one platform and unmarshall on another platform. Ideally the encoding should be decided upon so that the one used is consistent between the two platforms.